# How can I publish Angular web (custom) component as npm package?

Tags: angular, web, components

I am unable publish angular web (custom) component into npm.
The Goal is to use web (custom) component in various angular and non angular projects (react, view, EJS).
Is there way to achieve that? If yes, what needs to be done for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can build and publish this component as a library.

see https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do that !

First Create Angular Custom Library:-

1. Create angular project

`ng new angular-library-project`

2. in this project, create angular library

`ng generate library <library-name>`
for instance:
`ng generate library reusable-library`

3. Now develop library and test it in parent project by simply importing library module in app

- i.e: import ReusableLibraryModule in AngularLibraryProjectModule
- to generate component or module in library instead of project use `--project` flag (i.e `ng g c text-input --project reuseable-library`)
- don't forget to add every created component and module `in public-api.ts`

4. now build library using command
   `ng build <project-name>` (i.e : `ng build reusable-library`)
5. go to build folder. i.e `dist/<project-name>`
6. login to your npm account (if dont have one, create on https://npmjs.org) using `npm login`
7. finally run `npm publish`